# Recording State of iframe(url) from within an Office Add-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, office-addins

So I am developing an office add in which will essentially contain an iframe which will be running an application we own.

The problem is, I want to contantly record the url of the iframe so that i can save this to the addin state, aloowing us to use that information to load the iframe to the correct url each time the addin is reopened.

I cant figure out a way to output the url from within the iframe each time it changes? here is a sample of what i have, this doesnt contain the application just a couple of sample pages:

Home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/FabricUI/MessageBanner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- For the Office UI Fabric, go to https://aka.ms/office-ui-fabric to learn more. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.components.min.css">


</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Home.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var iframew = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframew.src = '../SecondPage/SecondPage.html';
            iframew.id = 'iframe1';
            iframew.onload = iframeLoaded(this.contentWindow.location.href);

            document.body.appendChild(iframew);


        });
    };

    // Helper function for displaying notifications

    function iframeLoaded(location) {
        console.log("log", location);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant understand why people are downvoting this question, it was a genuine issue

Anyway, for anyone interested I solved this by attaching a a function after the iframe loads which outputs the url of the iframe at set interval periods

```
var iframew = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframew.id = 'iframe1';
        var baseUrl = '#YOUR BASE URL#';

        let openUrl = getProperty('openurl');
        if (!openUrl) {
            console.log('No saved url');
            iframew.src = baseUrl;

        }
        else {
            console.log('saved url');
            console.log(openUrl);
            iframew.src = openUrl;

        }
        //when iframe loads attach function to save at interval
        iframew.addEventListener('load', function () { setInterval(function () { iframeLoaded(iframew.contentWindow.location.hash, iframew.contentWindow.location.href); }, 4000); });
        document.body.appendChild(iframew);
```

here is the iframeLoaded Function which also does some manipulation of the url and calles another function which saves the url to the doocument settings of the add-in:

```
function iframeLoaded(hash, location) {
            //if not in an analysis dont save
            if (hash.indexOf('#/dataset/') !== -1 ) {
                console.log("Same url")
                return
            }
           //remove # from hash
            hash = hash.substr(1);
            //concatenate base and hash
            let newUrl = baseUrl + hash;
            console.log(hash)
            console.log(newUrl);
            //save
            if (Office.context.document.settings) {
                saveProperty('openurl', newUrl);
            }
        }
```